# pytorch training loss invariant with varying forward pass implementations

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, mnist

The following code (MNIST MLP in PyTorch) delivers approximately the same training loss regardless of having the last layer in the forward pass returning:

1. F.log_softmax(x)
2. (x)

Option 1 is incorrect because I use `criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` and yet the results are almost identical. Am I missing anything?

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import time
from torchvision import datasets
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
# number of subprocesses to use for data loading
num_workers = 0
# how many samples per batch to load
batch_size = 20

# convert data to torch.FloatTensor
transform = transforms.ToTensor()

# choose the training and test datasets
train_data = datasets.MNIST(root='data', train=True,
                                   download=True, transform=transform)
test_data = datasets.MNIST(root='data', train=False,
                                  download=True, transform=transform)

# prepare data loaders
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=batch_size,
    num_workers=num_workers)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=batch_size,
    num_workers=num_workers)

import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        # linear layer (784 -> 1 hidden node)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(28 * 28, 512)
        self.dropout1= nn.Dropout(p=0.2, inplace= False)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 256)
        self.dropout2= nn.Dropout(p=0.2, inplace= False)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.2, inplace= False)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(256, 10)


    def forward(self, x):
        # flatten image input
        x = x.view(-1, 28 * 28)
        # add hidden layer, with relu activation function
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
#        return F.log_softmax(x)
        return x

# initialize the NN
model = Net()
print(model)
model.to('cuda')
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
n_epochs = 10

model.train() # prep model for training

for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    # monitor training loss
    train_loss = 0.0

    start = time.time()
    for data, target in train_loader:
        data, target = data.to('cuda'), target.to('cuda')

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(data)
        loss = criterion(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        train_loss += loss.item()*data.size(0)

    train_loss = train_loss/len(train_loader.dataset)

    print('Epoch: {} \tTraining Loss: {:.6f} \ttime: {:.6f}'.format(
        epoch+1,
        train_loss,
        time.time()-start
        ))
```

Answer (score 1):

For numerical stability, the `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` is implemented with the `softmax` layer inside it. So you should NOT use the softmax layer in your forward pass.

From the docs (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#crossentropyloss):

> This criterion combines nn.LogSoftmax() and nn.NLLLoss() in one single class.

Using the softmax layer in the forward pass will lead to worse metrics because the gradient magnitudes are lowered (thus, the weight updates are also lowered). I learned it the hard way!

I guess your problem is that the loss is similar at the beginning of training, but at the end of the training, they should not. It is usually a good sanity check to overfit your model in one batch of data. The model should reach 100% accuracy if the batch is small enough. If the model is taking too long to train than you probably have a bug somewhere.

Hope that helps =)

Comment: thank you. In this case, even after 50 epochs the 'wrong' code delivers almost identical accuracy as the correct one.

Comment: Have you tried to overfit your model in one batch of data? If it does not overfit that is because there is a bug somewhere in the code breaking the gradient flow. Or it may just be that the model is not expressive enough (too simplistic) for the task. A learning rate that is too high or too low may also affect your results

Comment: 50 epochs, no dropout (so I hoped this will cause overfitting), and using the wrong code, but the results are absolutely fine